# Domain of definition of the solution of a Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I need your help for the following  Cauchy problem:

> $$ y '(t) = (y (t) +9) ^ 2 \quad \text{with} \quad y (0) = 4 $$

I am trying to figure out on which domain, is the solution of this EDO defined?

I think the answer is entire $\mathbb {R} $. Is it correct ?

What I did:

Let's make the substitution $x(t) = (y(t) +9)$
Then the ODE is equivalent to: $x'(t)=x(t)^2$
I didn't go further because my goal is not to solve it but only to check the Domain of definition.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The differential equation $x'(t)=x(t)(1+e^{-t})$ is wrong and not equivalent to the original differential equation.

Comment: Thanks, @Fakemistake, I fixed it, the edits are pending approval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is not correct, as you will see. We have techniques to know if the domain will be the whole $\mathbb{R}$ but here you may try to solve the equation to know where it is defined exaclty if it is not. Here is a way :

Doing the substition $z(t)=y(t)+9$ yeilds :

$z'(t)=z(t)^2$ with $z(0)=13$.

Then try to solve using separation of variables.

Comment: When trying to solve it using separation of variable I find : $z(t) = \frac{13}{1-13t}$, so the domain of definition would be: $\mathbb{R} \backslash  \frac{1}{13}$ ?

Comment: @MarwanB : The domain of a solution of an ODE is always a (connected) interval. You have to choose the correct one of the two.

Comment: @LutzL: I'm stuck. Could you please advise why it is always the case?
Would it be because when we integrate to get the solution we need continuous functions? 
Why would I choose $]-\infty, \frac{1}{13}]$ over $]\frac{1}{13}, +\infty[$?

Comment: @MarwanB : The definition/construction of a maximal solution as maximal extension by concatenation of local solutions demands connectedness. The given initial point $x_0=0$ has to be inside the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Try separation of variables:

$ \frac{dy}{(y+9)^2}=dx$.